# jQuery .live and .delegate() addClass and removeClass dynamically problems

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I'm trying to add and remove a class on a click event with no results.
I'm working on Drupal 7 with jquery 1.4 and the bookmark links are generate by flag module.

I will explain what I need to do.
I have got a piece o html code like this :

```
<div class="container"><a class="bookmark">Bookmark</a></div>
<div class="container"><a class="flag bookmark">Bookmark</a></div>
```

Now when you click on "Bookmark", automatically (by module flag) the classes of the links change (it changes via AJAX and the link will rebuilt)

```
<div class="container"><a class="flag bookmark">Bookmark</a></div>
<div class="container"><a class="flag bookmarked">Bookmarked</a></div>
```

What I want to do is to give a class to the container, so I wrote

```
$('.bookmarked').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('this-bookmarked');}
});
$('.bookmark').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('this-bookmarked');}
});
```

This works on the first, it does not work like a "toggle".

I've tried to use .live() but with no result, It does not work at all.

```
$("a.flag").live({
     click: function() {
         if ($(this).parent().hasClass("this-bookmarked")) {
             $(this).parent().removeClass('this-bookmarked');           
         } else {  
             $(this).parent().addClass('this-bookmarked');
         }

        return false;}
});
```

I tried this as well

```
$("a.flag").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("this-bookmarked")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('this-bookmarked');            
    } else {  
        $(this).parent().addClass('this-bookmarked');
    }

    return false;}
});
```

to be sure I've used .delegate() too

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(document).delegate("a.flag", "click", function() {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("this-bookmarked")) {
            jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('this-bookmarked');           
        } else {  
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('this-bookmarked');
        }
        return false;}
    );
});
```

Both .live() and .delegate() don't give me any result and any error even if I want to alert some text. Am i doing something wrong?

Should I use some other jquery API?

Many thanks

Comment: toggleClass() works for the first action, if I click again it does not work because after you click the link it will be rebuild via AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$('a.flag').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('this-bookmarked');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry.  Forgot to close my jQuery block.  Edited and it does work.  jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/k7Wf9/